# How do I create a new SQL database in Visual Studio 2015 for the first time?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

I'm very confused, when I try to create a new database in Visual Studio 2015 when I right-click --> Add new item --> SQL Server Database, I get an error saying "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server." I think this means I don't have the SQL Server running, which is correct.

But when I try to start the SQL Server, it gives me the error "Windows could not start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) on Local Computer) (Error code 17113). The event viewer gives me this error "Error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.) occurred while opening file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary." which I believe means that it won't start because there is no database.

So how am I supposed to create a database on a running SQL server when the SQL server won't run unless it has a database?

I don't know if this is relevant but I created it as an ASP.NET empty web site.

Comment: can you check on services.msc if SQLEXPRESS is running?

Comment: no, it won't run, it gives me the error message from the 2nd paragraph

Comment: go to Configuration Manager-->right click on the sql server service and go to ---> Properties and you should see Start up parameters tab what's inside this?

Comment: ok, i found it, SQL Server Configuration Manager.....

-dC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf

-eC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG

-lC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf

Comment: nah it's okay, the parameters its saying is the -d -e -I before the path,can you check all path if those files really exist?

edited: if there's -f parameter, remove it

Comment: the 1st and 3rd ones did not exist, in fact the DATA folder did not exist. The second one existed but it asked me for permission to access the folder

Comment: not sure if this is relevant, but when I installed SQL server i did not check the box off that said "LocalDB"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108785/discussion-between-zev-and-jc-borlagdan).

Comment: i can't chat now, i'm at work actually, just trying to check once in a while,.. i guess you need to reinstall your sql, and update your sql in visual studio.. It might got interrupted during installation